# SAS: ERROR 180-322 but it's not semicolon

Tags: sas

I'm getting an error and I have no clue why. I've been checking for missing semicolons but couldn't find any missing. I'm also copy pasting everything from working macro.

### ERROR I'M GETTING:

```
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro TERMIANL_RET_SCORES not resolved.
SYMBOLGEN: DATE_CALC resolved to 202011
MPRINT(GATHERSCORES):   %termianl_ret_scores(date_calc = 202011, add_months = -6, how_many = 9);
NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "GATHERSCORES".
1540            %termianl_ret_scores(date_calc = &date_calc, add_months = -6, how_many = 9);
                _
                180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

MPRINT(GATHER):  ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro **TERMIANL**_RET_SCORES not resolved.

I would try to figure this first.  Did you spell TERMINAL wrong? Or did it fail to compile?

Fix errors and warnings from the TOP down.

Comment: Oh god, thanks. I was calling TERMINAL insted of TERMIANL